# Folium.geojson Multiline String doesn't wrap around the map, creates crossing lines across the map

Tags: geojson, folium, antimeridian, crossing, multiline

I am having an issue using Python and folium regarding GeoJSON features.
I made a simple map using folium and displayed tsunami information as well as specific colors for the different earthquake magnitudes.

I also wanted to include a GeoJSON of subduction zones that I found online, but the issue is that some MultiLine Strings have coordinates switching from -179 to +179 inwithin, and that creates those huge crossing lines across the entire map as such:

[image: Overview of the map]

The issue is that I would love to fix this issue in Python, either by using another module (which I haven't found anything about, especially when the rest of the map and map features are linked to folium).
Perhaps something like making two versions of the GeoJSON; one with only positive values and the other with negative values only (longitude only I'm guessing) would work but I've been trying and do not see how I can make this happen.

Perhaps the best way would be to switch modules for this GeoJSON in particular? The oceanic ridge GeoJSON I imported, in the other hand, worked fine and drew lines beyond 180 in longitude.

Comment: Have a look at the first answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697248/display-geojson-with-leaflet-that-spans-the-180th-meridian

Comment: Can you add a link to GeoJSON of subduction zones?

Comment: I will try when I get home, thank you TomazicM. I'm sorry I didn't check this earlier.

Comment: I could not find the original github anywhere but here it is unmodified uploaded on my own gist https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Daltaxy/136faa3e0f2facf1bf545f2441824a6b/raw/b27bc1b6de0716975fe11a5cfc19b65921b12e19/Slab2_depth.geojson

Comment: sadly it did not work despite converting the function to python (it was javascript), the map displays eventually but the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so I actually ended up fixing it after a few hours of struggle.
First I needed to convert the javascript from the linked thread to python, change some names for my project and use the requests module in order to avoid sending any superfluous files other than the python file. I basically used the idea provided in the thread to fix my issue

I then had to duplicate the code for the West side of the map (Ouest in french); I do not know if there is a non redundant way to do it.

Oh and I also had to make sure I was only changing the longitude (i % 2 == 0 ?)

Here's what I end up with:

```
zones_subduction_geojson = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Daltaxy/136faa3e0f2facf1bf545f2441824a6b/raw/b27bc1b6de0716975fe11a5cfc19b65921b12e19/Slab2_depth.geojson'
reponse = requests.get(zones_subduction_geojson)

with open('zones_subduction.geojson', 'w') as f: #w pour write, f variable aléatoire
    f.write(reponse.text)

with open('zones_subduction.geojson', 'r') as g: #r pour read, g variable aléatoire
    zones_est = geojson.load(g)

with open('zones_subduction.geojson', 'r') as h: #r pour read, h variable aléatoire
    zones_ouest = geojson.load(h)

def est(coords):
    if isinstance(coords, list):
        for i in range(len(coords)):
            if isinstance(coords[i], list):
                est(coords[i])
            elif isinstance(coords[i], float):
                # Check if it's a longitude coordinate (even index)
                if i % 2 == 0 and coords[i] < 0:
                    coords[i] = 180 + (180 + coords[i])

def ouest(coords):
    if isinstance(coords, list):
        for i in range(len(coords)):
            if isinstance(coords[i], list):
                ouest(coords[i])
            elif isinstance(coords[i], float):
                # Check if it's a longitude coordinate (even index)
                if i % 2 == 0 and coords[i] > 0:
                    coords[i] = -180 + (-180 + coords[i])

for feature in zones_est['features']:
    geometry = feature['geometry']
    if geometry['type'] == 'MultiLineString':
        for line_coords in geometry['coordinates']:
            est(line_coords)

with open('zones_subduction_est.geojson', 'w') as i:
    geojson.dump(zones_est, i)

for feature in zones_ouest['features']:
    geometry = feature['geometry']
    if geometry['type'] == 'MultiLineString':
        for line_coords in geometry['coordinates']:
            ouest(line_coords)

with open('zones_subduction_ouest.geojson', 'w') as j:
    geojson.dump(zones_ouest, j)


m = folium.Map(location=[0,0], zoom_start=2)
folium.GeoJson('zones_subduction_est.geojson', name='Zones de Subduction Est', style_function=lambda x: {'color': 'red', 'weight': 2, 'opacity': 0.5}).add_to(m)
folium.GeoJson('zones_subduction_ouest.geojson', name='Zones de Subduction Ouest', style_function=lambda x: {'color': 'red', 'weight': 2, 'opacity': 0.5}).add_to(m)
```

This works perfectly and allowed me to end up with this result:
[image: Fixed Map]

Indeed, the display now goes very far but it's no problem, I'd say it's even better that way.

Thank you TomazicM for the guidance